# How to remove an element from a list?

Tags: c++, c, list, pointers, delete-operator

Here's some code:

```
typedef struct n
{
    int value;
    struct n *next;
}ELEMENT;
```

.

```
typedef struct
{
    ELEMENT *head;
    ELEMENT *tail;
}INFO;
```

Heres a function that doesn't work:

```
void LIST::remove(int x)
{
ELEMENT *q = inf.head;

    while(q!=NULL)
    {
        if((q->value)==x)
        {
            ELEMENT * temp = q;
            q = q->next;
            delete temp;
            break;

        }
        else
            q=q->next;
    }
}
```

I don't understand why removing an element from a list doesn't work. Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: Could you elaborate on _'doesn't work'_ please?

Comment: this remove function doesn't do its work.

Comment: You need to keep in account the `previous` node also as you are deleting the node in the middle of the list and not at the beginning.

Comment: What is the relation between structure INFO and LIST?!

Comment: You could use the STLs `std::list` which are on `<list>` and the `std::remove` function from the `<algorithm>`

Answer (score 4):

Small hint: take some paper and pencil and draw some boxes and arrows and simulate what you are doing: when you found the item that should be deleted you just delete the element but do neither adapt the `next` pointer of the previous item nor the head or tail pointer. So after the deletation there is an element that has a `next` pointer that points to an invalid memory location (a so called dangling pointer). What you want to do is to have an additional pointer to the previous item to adapt its `next` pointer.

Comment: best way to understand his code. I believe he should have done this first, and then make the code

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to reassign the `next` pointer of the deleted node's previous element to the deleted element's `next` pointer. Edit: you also forgot to handle `head` and `tail` pointers, as I did initially.

```
void LIST::remove(int x)
{
    ELEMENT *q = inf.head;
    ELEMENT prev = NULL;

    while(q != NULL)
    {
        if(q->value == x)
        {
            if (q == inf.head)
                inf.head = q->next;
            else
                prev->next = q->next;
            if (q == inf.tail)
                inf.tail = prev;
            delete q;
            break;

        }
        else
        {
            prev = q;
            q=q->next;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That at least removes the element correctly. But he still has to check the `head` and `tail` pointer if the first or last element is removed (especially if an empty list is created by removing the last element).

Answer (score 0):

you  need  to  keep  the  previous  element  too,  and  set  it's  next  to  be q-> next  beside  of  what  you   already do

Answer (score 0):

Your removing an element from the list does not work because the function is wrong. You do not take into account whether the removed element is the head or tail of the list and you do not set field next of the previous element.

Try the following code

```
void LIST::remove(int x)
{
   ELEMENT *p = NULL;
   ELEMENT *q = inf.head;

    while ( q != NULL && q->value != x )
    {
        p = q;
        q = q->next;
    }

    if ( q )
    {
        if ( p == NULL )
        {
            inf.head = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            p->next = q->next;
        }

        if (  inf.tail == q )
        {
            inf.tail = p;
        }

        delete q;
    } 
}
```